# Anatomy of a Postback

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, postback

How do I determine the `Params` sent by a `POST` method?

If I have a `button`, and that `button` is clicked, what is sent to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enumerate the Request.Form you will see all the data sent by the POST.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
         Response.Write(key + " :: " + Request.Form[key] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

However, you should not access the data this way if you are using ASP.NET Server Controls. You should access the relevant property of that control. e.g.

```
// For a TextBox
TextBox1.Value; 

// For a DropDownList
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx) property.